# I am building a macro that goes to the next row when button is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

About: I do have two tabs named "Merge" and the other "PersonRet". I am printing letters from the "Merge" tab where the button is. The letters get data from"PersonRet" tab using the concatenate formula. FYI: The letter: The letter is already written but has some gaps where we use the concatenate formula to pick the answers from each row in the other tab. In short, each row completes one letter which is printed. The next row is for another letter and has different data.(All this part is built. Only issue is having the button to work when clicked, so it goes to the next row)

Goal: Be able to click the button after printing the 1st letter in row 2 from column A to K. Click the button again, and it goes to row 3 column A to k and so on. After it after all rows are done, I'd like to have a message box saying: "Sorry: you've already reached the end"
Thank you for your time & help

```vb
Sub Next_Click()
    
Dim notFirst As Boolean
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
     
Sheets("Merge").Select
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print lastRow
For i = 2 To lastRow
    
Sheets("PersonalRet").Select
If notFirst Then
    If rng.Row = "A" & i Then
        MsgBox "Sorry: you've already reached the end"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    End If
Else
    'Set rng = Range("A" & i)
    Set rng = Range("A2")
    notFirst = True
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The spaces might have originated when i pasted the code to word and then posted it here

Comment: Fixed - please try to condense your code by removing extra lines.  code that's too spread out is difficult to follow

Comment: Hey Tim, thank you for the opportunity. I have removed the spaces

Comment: I can't see how your code joins up with your explanation of what happens with the letters.  One thing though:  `If rng.Row = "A" & i Then`.   `rng` isn't defined at that point so will equal _nothing_ so you can't get the row from it, and `rng.Row` would return a numeric value - 1, 2, 3, etc.  `"A" & i` will return a string - A1, A2, A3, etc.  If anything it looks like it should be `If rng.Row = i Then`.